# discord.js module Issue crashing the bot

Tags: discord.js

In the last few times my bot kept crashing from this error

```
 const existing = this.cache.get(data.id);
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

the error comes from the discord.js module files, I'm not quite sure if it my code I haven't changed anything recently and the error came out of nowhere an Image is also included with error details[image: Error details]

Comment: `data` is returning `undefined`

Comment: Where does the variable data come from? We need more code here